# How to slice over a labeled index + 1, python?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3],['a','b','c'])
print(df)
   0
a  1
b  2
c  3

df.loc('a')
0    1
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

But now I want to get the value for `b` (2), only trying to use `df.loc('a'+ 1 )` which is not working. If `b` is unknown but after `a`, how to solve this problem? And what if you want `df.loc('a'+ 1 :)`?

Answer (score 1):

You need [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for positions and then select by [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
def get_next(val):
    return min(df.index.get_loc(val) + 1, len(df.index) - 1)

print (get_next('a'))
1
print (get_next('b'))
2
print (get_next('c'))
2

print (df.iat[get_next('a'), 0])
2
print (df.iat[get_next('b'), 0])
3
print (df.iat[get_next('c'), 0])
3
```

Answer (score 1):

`try` / `except` is a pythonic solution. Use [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) for fast integer lookups.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], ['a','b','c'])

try:
    idx = df.index.get_loc('a') + 1
except IndexError:
    idx = len(df.index)

idx
# 1

df.iat[idx, 0]
# 2
```